# PDO prepared statement on UPDATE is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to UPDATE table with a prepared statement, for some reason I have a hard time doing it as I keep getting an error with the statement.
I am using prepared statements often and not sure what I am missing.

That is what I got (part of a function):

```
       $result = array();

    try {

        $sql  = "UPDATE UsersData SET firstName = :firstName, lastName = :lastName, birthDay = :birthDay, aboutMe = :aboutMe, facebookU = :facebookU, twitterU = :twitter, githubU = :github WHERE uId =: id";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':firstName' => $userInformation['firstName'],
            ':lastName'  => $userInformation['lastName'],
            ':birthDay'  => $userInformation['birthDay'],
            ':aboutMe'   => $userInformation['aboutMe'],
            ':facebookU' => $userInformation['facebook'],
            ':twitterU'  => $userInformation['twitter'],
            ':github'    => $userInformation['github'],
            ':id'        => $userInformation['id']
        ));
        $result = true;

    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        $result = "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $result;
```

I get

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in
```

On line

```
$stmt->execute(array(
```

I tried as well:

```
   $result = array();

    try {

        $sql = "UPDATE UsersData AS UD, Users AS US
        SET
        UD.firstName=:firstName,
        UD.lastName=:lastName,
        UD.birthDay=:birthDay,
        UD.aboutMe=:aboutMe,
        UD.facebookU=:facebookU,
        UD.twitterU=:twitter,
        UD.githubU=:github
        US.uEmail=:email
        WHERE UD.uId=:id AND US.id=:id";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':firstName' => $userInformation['firstName'],
            ':lastName'  => $userInformation['lastName'],
            ':birthDay'  => $userInformation['birthDay'],
            ':aboutMe'   => $userInformation['aboutMe'],
            ':facebookU' => $userInformation['facebook'],
            ':twitterU'  => $userInformation['twitter'],
            ':github'    => $userInformation['github'],
            ':id'        => $userInformation['id']
        ));
        $result = true;

    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        $result = "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $result;
```

Got the same error.

I found a solution but I am not sure why it would work like that and not the other ways:

```
$sql  = "UPDATE UsersData SET firstName =?, lastName =?, birthDay =?, aboutMe =?, facebookU =?, twitterU =?, githubU =? WHERE uId = ?";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute([
            $userInformation['firstName'],
            $userInformation['lastName'],
            $userInformation['birthDay'],
            $userInformation['aboutMe'],
            $userInformation['facebook'],
            $userInformation['twitter'],
            $userInformation['github'],
            $userInformation['id']
        ]);
```

Thank in advance!

Comment: Your `prepare` failed (`: id` should be `:id`). You need to look at `$this->connect()->errorInfo`.

Comment: Thanks, but still getting this error:
<b>Warning</b>:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in <b>*path*</b> on line <b>560</b><br />

Comment: You have a parameter called `:twitter` but you are setting `:twitterU` in the inputs. You need to look for *all* of these issues...

Comment: Updated with a solution, not sure why it is working..

Comment: I told you what the problem was in my last comment...

Comment: Thanks, @Nick  looks like we reply at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prepare statement fails and results in a boolean value instead of a resource.

You're missing a comma in you query, try the following:

```
UPDATE
  UsersData AS UD,
  Users AS US
SET
  UD.firstName = :firstName,
  UD.lastName = :lastName,
  UD.birthDay = :birthDay,
  UD.aboutMe = :aboutMe,
  UD.facebookU = :facebookU,
  UD.twitterU = :twitter,
  UD.githubU = :github,
  US.uEmail = :email
WHERE
  UD.uId = :id
  AND US.id = :id
```

Comment: Are you sure about that?